# Junction object allows to create only one related list

Tags: relationships, related-list, junction-object

I have created a junction object that relates Case (with related list "A") and Account (with related list "B") objects with each other. I want to place both Related Lists on the Case Layout page, but for some reason only related list "B" of the Account object is available to include on this layout from the Related Lists selection box. The related list "A" bar does not even appear in the Related Lists box to select fields, lists, quick actions etc. from. How can I make it work to include both of the lists?

Answer (score 0):

This is working as expected. You can't add the Case related list to a Case layout as your junction object will be linking that Case to many Account records. You'll see the same behavior if you attempt this from the Account object.